# switch between language files within a joomla 3 component to send multilingual emails

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I've created a multilingual component that has a front end form for the user to make a request.   I want to reply to the user in their native language and send a copy to the site owner in their 'admin' language.
The only way I have figured out how to do it so far is to first create a message using the current site language, then load the admin language file, recreate the message then reload the user language file.  Is this the best way to do it or am I missing something?

```
$language =& JFactory::getLanguage(); //load language
$language_tag = $language->getTag(); // loads the current language-tag
$adminlang = $this->params->get('adminLang','en-GB');
$usermessage = JText::_('COM_BOOKINGS_BOOKING_FIELD_FIRST_NAME_LABEL'). ": " . $data['first_name'] . "\r\n";
$usermessage .= JText::_('COM_BOOKINGS_BOOKING_FIELD_LAST_NAME_LABEL') . ": " . $data['last_name'] . "\r\n";
// etc etc
if ($adminlang != $language_tag) {
    $language->load('com_bookings' , dirname(__FILE__), $adminlang, true); // load the admin language
    $adminmessage = JText::_('COM_BOOKINGS_BOOKING_FIELD_FIRST_NAME_LABEL'). ": " . $data['first_name'] . "\r\n";
    $adminmessage .= JText::_('COM_BOOKINGS_BOOKING_FIELD_LAST_NAME_LABEL') . ": " . $data['last_name'] . "\r\n";
    // etc etc
    $language->load('com_bookings' , dirname(__FILE__), $language_tag, true);  //reload the user language
}else{
    $adminmessage = $usermessage;
}
```